# RegExp extraction

Tags: regex

Here's the input string:

```
loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif)
```

With this RegExp: **\'.+.xml\'**

... we get this:

```
'mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml'
```

... but I want to extract only this:

```
http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml
```

Any suggestions? I'm sure this problem has been asked before, but it's difficult to search for. I'll be happy to Accept a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: what flavour of regex is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get everything within quotes that starts with http:

```
(?<=')http:[^']+(?=')
```

If you only want those ending with .xml

```
(?<=')http:[^']+\.xml(?=')
```

- It doesn't select the quotation marks (as you asked)
- It's fast!

Fair warning: it only works if the regex engine you're using can handle lookbehind

Comment: I tried to study your solution so that I can understand it, but I'm uncertain about the = sign. What does it do? A few popular RegEx sites I've checked do not mention the = sign at all. Thanks.

Comment: It's part of the look-behind syntax: (?<=). It's covered pretty well here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

in .net this regex works for me:

```
\'[\w:/.]+\.xml\'
```

breaking it down:

- a ' character
- followed by a word character or ':' or '/' or '.' any number of times (which matches the url bit)
- followed by '.xml' (which differentiates the sought string from the other urls which it will match without this)
- followed by another ' character

I tested it [here](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx)

**Edit**
  I missed that you don't want the quotes in the result, in which case as has been pointed out you need to use look behind and look ahead to include the quotes in the search, but not in the answer.  again in .net:

```
(?<=')[\w:/.]+\.xml(?=')
```

but I think the best solution is a combination of those offered already:

```
(?<=')[^']+\.xml(?=')
```

which seems the simplest to read, at least to me.

Comment: You've mixed up the escaping of the dots - remove the backslash inside the character class, add one before the final dot.

Comment: @Tim both variations work on the given input, but you are right about the backslash before the final dot as we want it to be explicitly a dot

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the language would be helpful. Basically, you are having a problem because the + quantifier is *greedy*, meaning it will match the largest part of the string that it can. you need to use a non-greedy quantifier, which will match as little as possible.

We will need to know the language you're in to know what the syntax for the non-greedy quantifier should be.

[Here is a perl recipe](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm). Just as a sidenote, instead of .+, you probably want to match [^.]+.xml.

```
\'.+?.xml\'
```

should work if your language supports perl-like regexes.

Comment: I selected the other answer, but your information still proved useful and I learned greedy vs. non-greedy. It'll help me write regexes in the future. Cheers.

The language is Java/JSP by the way. We're using the "transformText" JSP tag library (found in www.infoglue.org, a Java-based CMS like Drupal etc.). I'm not exactly sure if if that's Perl style.

Comment: glad it helped! understanding greedy vs non-greedy (sometimes called "stingy") will save you many debugging headaches in the future!

Answer (score 2):

This should work (*tested in javascript, but pretty sure it would work in most cases*)

```
'[^']+?\.xml'
```

it looks for these rules

- starts with `'`
- is followed by anything *but* `'`
- ends in `.xml'`

you can demo it at http://RegExr.com?2tp6q

Comment: This worked too. I accepted the other answer because I wanted the output to not include the quotes. Upvoted anyway. Cheers.